# CSS reuse in external stylesheet

Tags: css, class

Imagine I have several classes defined in external stylesheet

```
.b {font-weight:bold;}
.c {text-align:center;}
```

now I want another class which is a combination of b and c

```
.bc
```

is it possible to define class bc using classes b and c, or should I write full

```
.bc {font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
```

Comment: DRY! just use it on html tags like : `<div class="b c"></div>` and it will get properties of both classes!

Comment: If you really want to do this solely in your stylesheet, consider using a preprocessor like Sass. http://sass-lang.com/. (Namely, take a look at the power of mixins, which you should be able to leverage in your situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Just include both classes in the HTML and it should do the job just fine for you.

```
<div class="b c">div content</div>
```

The "b" and "c" in the `class=` will get the styling from both. You can even add more to it, e, f, g... etc.

Comment: My intention is to combine classes on the CSS stylesheet level, not html level